# Adding Camera Preview in CCGLSurfaceView (Android Cocos2d)

Tags: android-camera, cocos2d-android

I want to have Camera Preview as background in CCLayer so how I can add camera preview in CCGLSurfaceView?

I am able to add camera preview in FrameLayout which is part of main xml file but to work with cocos2d I have to set the ContentView as CCGLSurfaceView not the Android Surface View with XML.